# Choice Filter returns no results for calculated column

Tags: 2013, list-view, filter

I'm trying to implement a Choice Filter Web App to filter the shown list entries based on the selection within the Choice Filter.

My list contains the column `Product Version` which is of the form `XX.XX.XXX`, e.g. `2.03.001`. The formula for the calculated column is `=LEFT([Product Version],INT(FIND(".",[Product Version])-1))` and calculates to `2` for the former example.

However, the list is always empty as soon as I select the option `2` (or any other) in the Choice Filter. On the other hand, if I switch Consumer Field Name to `Product Version` and add the option `2.03.001` to the list of choices, I get the corresponding list entry as expected.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it works for me. Make sure your calculated column is type Single Line of Text, not Number.

Comment: Thank you! The cause of my problem was that the data type was 'Number' which I changed to 'Single Line of Text' as you suggested. The filter now works as expected.